# C# - HttpWebResponse Header Not Being Set

Tags: c#, http-headers, content-length, weboperationcontext

I'm attempting to set the content-length of my outgoing response headers but my code seems to have no effect on the headers.

```
    web_op_context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Set("Content-Type", http_req.content_type);
    web_op_context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Length", "10");
    web_op_context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    web_op_context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Remove("Server");
    web_op_context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
```

The line for adding content-length and removing "Server" and "X-Powered-By" seems to not be rendering any change in my outgoing response headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Server and X-Powered By messages are being sent by IIS, not your code.  You have to disable them in IIS prevent them from being sent.

Answer (score 0):

The server and Powered by headers are added outside of your code, by the server. I recently had to remove these because they were flagged in a security scan as warnings. Here is the link I used to remove them. [Link i used](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506093425/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120209-1.aspx).